# PyMongo cursor operations are very slow

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to both MongoDB and pyMongo,
and am having some performance issues 
regarding cursors.

TL,DNR: Anything operation I try to perform
using a cursor takes about a second.

Long version

I have a small database, which I bulkloaded. Each entry has 3 fields:

dom:  domain name (unique)
date: date, YYYYMMDD
flag: string

I've loaded about 1.9 million entries, without incident, and quite quickly.

I created a hash index on the dom field.

Now, I want to grab certain records by the domain field, and update them, using a Python program.

That's where the problem lies.

I'm using the latest MongoDB, and the latest pyMongo.

stripped down program...

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = client.myindexname
posts = db.posts

print list(db.profiles.index_information()) # shows hash index is present

for k in newdomainlist.keys():          #iterate list of domains to check
  ret = posts.find({"dom": k})          #this runs fine, and quickly 
                                        #'ret' is a cursor
  print ret                             #this runs quickly
  #Here's the problem
  print ret.count()                     #this takes about a second. why?
```

---

If I just 'print ret', the speed is fine. However, if I try to
reference *anything* in the cursor, the speed drops to the floor - I
can do about 1 operation per second.

In this case, I'm just trying to see if ret.count() returns '0' (we don't
have this domain), or '1' (we have it already).

I've tried adding a batch_size(10000) to the find, without it helping.

I DO have the Python C extensions loaded.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Is `newdomainlist` a list ? why do you think you need "Hashed Index"?

Comment: The hashed index is on the 'dom' column in the MongoDB database. The new domainlist is a Python dictionary, and is simply where I'm obtaining the names to check for in the db.  Without a hashed index, access to the db was very slow. After adding the index, I can obtain cursors into the db quickly, but any usage of the cursor is (once again) very slow.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I'd created my hashed index on the wrong field, 'collection', rather than 'posts'. Chalk it up to mongodb inexperience. We can close this one now, or delete it entirely.